Next does not recognize changes happening in custom server unless I re-run the application
I am using Express.js on backend, and Next typescript on frontend, in order to properly connect next with a custom server, I followed the instructions in this documentation page:
Configuring: Custom Server
Here is my app.js code in express side:
const express = require('express')
//const proxy = require('express-http-proxy')
const parser = require('body-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const {pool} = require('./routes/routes')

const pgSessionStore = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);


function nextAppWrapper(nextApp){

const app = express()
const port = 3000

const {router}  = require('./routes/routes')
const cors = require('cors')

corsConfig = {
  methods:'*',
  credentials:true
}


app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy




app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})


app.use(cors(corsConfig))

app.use(session(
  {
  store: new pgSessionStore({
    pool:pool,
    tableName:'session',
    createTableIfMissing:true
    
  }),
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,httpOnly: true , domain:'127.0.0.1:3000'},
  saveUninitialized: true,
}))




app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(parser.json())
app.use('/api',router)
//app.use(proxy('http://127.0.0.1:3000'))

const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler()

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  return handle(req, res);
});


}

module.exports = nextAppWrapper


here is my code for server.ts file on Next side:
const nextAppWrapper = require('../backend/app')
const next = require('next')


const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const nextApp = next({dev})
nextApp.prepare().then(()=>{
    nextAppWrapper(nextApp)

})

So every-time I try to run npm run dev in console, and do a small change in backend, that change does not take effect unless I execute npm run dev again,
here is my package.json dep-list for express:

 "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.651.1",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.651.1",
    "@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.651.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.3",
    "connect-pg-simple": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.0",
    "express-http-proxy": "^2.1.1",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.15",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4",
    "pg": "^8.12.0",
    "pg-pool": "^3.6.2",
    "rewire": "^7.0.0",
    "sinon": "^19.0.2",
    "slugify": "^1.6.6",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5",
    "supertest": "^7.0.0",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0"
}

here is my package.json dep-list on next side:

"dependencies": {
    "@nextui-org/react": "^2.4.8",
    "@nextui-org/tooltip": "^2.0.41",
    "dompurify": "^3.1.7",
    "express-http-proxy": "^2.1.1",
    "hugeicons-react": "^0.3.0",
    "markdown-it": "^14.1.0",
    "markdown-it-jsx": "^1.1.0",
    "markdown-to-jsx": "^7.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "next": "14.2.10",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dompurify": "^3.0.5",
    "@types/markdown-it": "^14.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.10",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }

also, scripts
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.ts",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }

Please note that I am using 127.0.0.1 host with port 3000

Use their example with nodemon https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server

I get that I need to install nodemon on next side, and configure it by creating nodemon.json file?
